# Items in list are not being appended based on a common element

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to append lists based of common elements in each list.  TTL, ALG, and WOO. Any sugguestions?

```py
def dividethetexts(books, ttl, alg, woo):
    '''Divides each book into their own index.
    '''
    for line in books:
        data = line;
        data = data.strip()
        data = data.split("|")
        if data[0].lower() == 'ttl':
            ttl.append(data)
        elif data[0].lower() == 'alg':
            alg.append(data)
        elif data[0].lower() == 'woo':
            woo.append(data)
    print(data)
    return ttl, alg, woo
```

Comment: You should share the code that shows how you call this function, provide an example of the data in `books` and tell us a bit more about what results you're getting vs. the results you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some extra characters affecting your code, can you try this instead:

```py
def dividethetexts(books, ttl, alg, woo):
    '''Divides each book into their own index.
    '''
    for line in books:
        data = line.strip().split("|");
        if 'ttl' in data[0].lower():
            ttl.append(data)
        elif 'alg' in data[0].lower():
            alg.append(data)
        elif 'woo' in data[0].lower():
            woo.append(data)
    print(data)
    return ttl, alg, woo
```

I don't know the structure of your data, but it looks like you potentially could have blank spaces either at the beginning or end of `data[0]`.

Possibility #2:
Is possible also that simply `book` is empty, therefore the loop won't do anything.

Comment: Thank you for helping out! The data structure is below.  The goal is to get each of the the lines into a list in a list based off of TTL, ALG, and WOO.  Then to organize it based on number ascending. 
“I daresay you’ll see her soon,” said the Rose. “She’s one of the|478|ALG
“Nor I, sir,” Captain Nemo answered me. “I never touch the flesh of|2553|TTL
Having this thought in mind, the story of “The Wonderful Wizard of Oz”|46|WOO